# What is the file name used by default shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-backup-service

Android Backup Service [requires](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#SharedPreferences) a filename to backup shared preferences:

```
public static final String PREFS = "PrefFile";    
SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
```

It is clear what to use if filename is given during preferences creation like

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But I use default shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

What should I pass as `PREFS` value to `SharedPreferencesBackupHelper`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
private static String getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName() + "_preferences";
}
```

see your package name in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Is it safe to use hardcoded value `_preferences`? Will it work properly on all android devices?

Comment: It is not guaranteed. So I think it is better to use SP with defined name

Comment: Thanks. Is there any method to get the filename from the shared preferences?

Comment: This is now exposed as a public method on `PreferenceManager` in API 24: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(android.content.Context)

Comment: LA_ and owner of answer -  if there is no public method use Reflections - its better choice as constructing  some name from code - which is changing constantly (mean api)  - so - down vote for  such solutions

Answer (score 6):

From the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java#L373), The PackageName is based on the context that you pass in.

```
private static String getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName() + "_preferences";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `getDefaultSharedPreferencesName` method is private. Is there any public method to get it?

Comment: Couldn't you just add this method to your code and use it that way?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the comment to another answer, I am not sure if this is the right way to hardcode it - what will happen if Google changes it in the next Android version?

Comment: If you're worried about this changing in the next version why not just use your own key with `getSharedPreferences` then you won't ever have this issue. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1):

The default preference file's name is the calling activity's class name.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)