# How do I use Android 6.0 backup to restore default shared preferences?

Tags: android

I have an assortment of files I don't want backed up via the [new Marshmallow Autobackup feature](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) - a Realm database, a Shared Prefs file I use to store "most recently seen" information, log files etc.

Rather than using `<exclude ... />` for each of these, I'd prefer to simply back up the only file I *do* care about - user settings, stored in the **default** shared preferences. The docs indicate that using an `<include ... />` will automatically exclude every file not explicitly included.

What path do I use for the default Shared Preferences file?

```
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="?"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675159/what-is-the-file-name-used-by-default-shared-preferences), the default shared preferences filename is `your.package.name_preferences`. You can see this by running the following ADB command *after* they've been accessed at least once:

```
adb shell run-as your.package.name ls -al shared_prefs
```

Outputs:

```
C:\Users\Adam>adb shell run-as your.package.name ls -al shared_prefs
-rw------- u0_a158  u0_a158       351 1970-01-17 16:54 your.package.name_preferences.xml
```

In order to back this file up, you must specify it as follows, **including** the `.xml` at the end.

Update your manifest:

```
<manifest ...
    <application ...
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup">
    ....
</manifest>
```

And add `res/xml/backup.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="your.package.name_preferences.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

Note that you must include the `.xml` for *all* Shared Preferences file backups, even ones whose filename you've defined yourself - even though you don't include the `.xml` in the filename in code.

Comment: I found this article very helpful to go through the entire testing process: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html